# Python: Executing an application to install a program

Tags: python, windows-xp, windows-installer

I am using a python script to execute an application to install a program. Using `os.system('dir\\application.exe')` works.  However the installer has 2 installation parts and after completing the first one, it will hang there. The second one will only execute when I exit the python script. How can I get the whole installation process to complete without killing it in the script?

Answer (score 0):

from what you provided it is not clear why the installer is hanging. I've ran installers here and it works fine. Which installer are you running? Is it public available?

As a sidenote, don't use `os.system` to run your application. It needlessy invokes the shell -- use `subprocess` module instead:

```
subprocess.call(['dir/application.exe'])
```

Comment: I've tried using `subprocess.call()` too but the result was the same. For the installer, it's a Product Development Toolkit from Symbian available to registered users.  Here's the link to it:  https://developer-secure.symbian.org/main/tools_and_kits/downloads/view.php?id=9&vId=

Comment: @BiX: Yeah, that `subprocess.call` part was just a sidenote, not your issue's solution